# Grand Theft Auto V Setup Tool requires Windows Media Player

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v, windows-7

The title says it all, and I seem to have a bit of a problem with WMP. Windows just decides to be a horrible jerk and fails the installation in Windows Features. The failure is always accompanied by "An error has occured. Not all features were changed successfully." error message.

As any power user would do, I'm at my wit's end after attempting to fix the problem via the sfc /scannow command in CMD, and countless hours of Googling. All the help displayed is tutorials on how to enable WMP in Windows Features. What else can I do now? Is there some method to bypass the tool's detection of WMP?

I have the PC retail version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some versions of Windows 7 were released without WMP (windows 7N and 7KN) you can download a patch for this from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19289) which I assume will add the windows features you're lacking.

More info on the Windows 7N and 7KN versions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/94845/what-are-windows-7-n-kn-vl-editions)

Comment: My copy of Windows is Windows 7 Ultimate, and this version has WMP. But for some weird reason it's not installing. I think if Windows 7 N and KN versions don't have WMP then it shouldn't appear in the Windows Features. But mine has. So that's the weird part.

Comment: Rockstar have said: Windows Media Player is no longer required to install GTAV. Instead, Windows Media Foundation will be required. But it doesn't look to be the case for most people. After a google it looks like windows re-install is the only option at this time.

Comment: Yeah well apparently the retail copies won't be recalled, and we have to keep looking for the solution. Great, thank you Rockstar.

Comment: I'll see if there are any more answers, and if there aren't in the next few days I'll just mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: If you download the game from Rockstar using your retail key you should get the latest installer. You can download it via Social Club here: https://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/activate/index-signin

Comment: Am I supposed to download a file called "GTAV_Setup_Tool.exe"? If I am, then this is really absurd because the error is exactly the same! It's still stupidly trying to look for WMP.

Comment: yes mate. That's what is used to download the set-up files :\

Comment: Well yeah, the "latest" installer still looks for WMP.

Comment: You know what, the problem has been fixed. I finally musterd up my courage and reinstalled Windows 8.1. The game is now installing. Thanks for your time though!