# GTA V Setup Tool gives Media Feature Pack error

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v, windows-10

I've been trying to install GTA V using the official GTA V Setup Tool from Rockstar Games, but it doesn't work! It says that it requires Media Feature Pack.

[image: The Error]

How can I fix this? I'm using Windows 10 Pro N.

Comment: This is different from [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/218485/grand-theft-auto-v-setup-tool-requires-windows-media-player) as it is asking about Windows 7 and while the issue is the same, the fix requires different update installations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the issue while installing on a friend's PC. As it has an KN/N-version Windows, it lacks Media Feature Pack. To fix it, you need to install **ALL of these 4 updates, in the same order** (preferably both x86 and x64 versions):

[KB3010081](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48231)

[KB3099229](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49919)

[KB3133719](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53356)

[KB4016817](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/4016817)

After installing these four, we restarted the PC, and the game is now installing just fine.

Comment: If Windows 10 gets a major update and the relevant update link isn't provided here, please check this list ( https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3145500 ) and install the relevant version (and leave a comment so that I can update the answer's body).